# Strange behaviour in showing annotations images on map using data coming from Firebase. SWIFT 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, mkannotation, mkannotationview

The strange behaviour is that when I add a new annotation, either tapped or user location, it gets displayed with the right chosen icon.  When MapVC load for the first time,  the posts retrieved from Firebase have all the same icon, ( the icon name of the latest one posted. If, after posting a new one, I exit mapViewVc to the menuVC and re enter mapViewVC than every icon is displaying the same icon again, now being my previously posted one.
a Few times it happened the the icons were two different icons, randomly chosen.
I don't understand why the coordinates are taken right but the image is not.

The app flow is:
I have a mapView vc where I can either double tap on screen and get coordinate or code user location coordinate via a button and then get to an chooseIconVc where I have all available icons to choose for the annotation. Once I select one, the icon name get passed back in in mapViewVC in unwindHere() that stores icon name into a variable and coordinates into another. In postAlertNotification those variables get posted to Firebase.
In displayAlerts() the data from Firebase gets stored into variables to initialise an annotation and gets added to mapView.

chosen icon:

```
@IBAction func unwindHere(sender:UIStoryboardSegue) { // data coming back
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? IconsViewController {
        alertNotificationType = sourceViewController.dataPassed
        if tapCounter > 0  {

            alertNotificationLatitude = String(describing: alertCoordinates.latitude)
            alertNotificationLongitude = String(describing: alertCoordinates.longitude)
            postAlertNotification()      // post new notification to Firebase

        } else {

            alertCoordinates = self.trackingCoordinates
            alertNotificationLatitude = String(describing: self.trackingCoordinates!.latitude)
            alertNotificationLongitude = String(describing: self.trackingCoordinates!.longitude)
            postAlertNotification()   // post new notification to Firebase

        }

    }
}
```

than post:

```
func postAlertNotification() {

        // to set next notification id as the position it will have in array ( because first position is 0 ) we use the array.count as value


        let latitude = alertNotificationLatitude
        let longitude = alertNotificationLongitude
        let alertType = alertNotificationType

        let post: [String:String] = [//"Date" : date as! String,
                                     //"Time" : time as! String,
                                     "Latitude" : latitude as! String,
                                     "Longitude" : longitude as! String,
                                     "Description" : alertType as! String]

        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

    }
```

retrieve and display:

```
    func displayAlerts() {



        ref = Database.database().reference()



        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

//            defer { self.dummyFunctionToFoolFirebaseObservers() }
            guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }
            guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }

            //                let date = data!["Date"]
            //                let time = data!["Time"]
            let dataLatitude = data["Latitude"]!
            let dataLongitude = data["Longitude"]!
            self.alertIconToDisplay = data["Description"]!

            let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
            let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
            let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

            print("Firebase post retrieved !")

            print("Longitude Actual DataKey is \(String(describing: firebaseKey))")

            print("fir long \((snapshot.value!, snapshot.key))")
            self.userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: self.alertIconToDisplay!, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.userAlertAnnotation)


        })
    }
```

and

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: userAlertAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "")    //  CHANGE FOR NEW ANNOTATION : FULL DATA

        //added if statement for displaying user location blue dot
        if annotation is MKUserLocation{
            return nil
        } else {


            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: alertIconToDisplay!)                        //    choose the image to load

            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.27, y: 0.27)
            annotationView.transform = transform
            return annotationView
        }
    }
```

the variables declarations :

```
var alertIconToDisplay: String?
var userAlertAnnotation: UserAlert!  
var alertNotificationType: String?                                             
var alertNotificationLatitude: String? 
var alertNotificationLongitude: String?
```

UPDATE:

annotation cLass:

```
import MapKit


class UserAlert: NSObject , MKAnnotation {

    var type: String?

    var firebaseKey: String?

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    var image: UIImage?

    override init() {
    }
    init(type:String, coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D, firebaseKey: String) {

        self.type = type
        self.firebaseKey = firebaseKey

        self.coordinate = coordinate

    }
}
```

Comment: You should really explain more. Make clear what classes you have, and how they are used, and definitely which class these functions belong to.
Note, by the way, that you are handling the 'alertIconToDisplay' differently than the coordinates, so that is probably the base for why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: I thought so, meaning coordinates are taken straight from incoming data but image from a global variable

Comment: would be helpful to edit the question showing just one entire code?

Comment: So the image (I assume you mean 'alertIconToDisplay') is a global variable? That was not clear from the code, which is why you need to state your class structure (which classes you have and how they relate to each other), and which class the functions you list belong to. Showing your whole code is usually not useful, because people are not prepared to read through a lot of code.

Comment: If the image is a global variable, why are you surprised that it is the same for all objects? That is the definition of what 'global' means.

Comment: I was expecting that it would store the value from firebase and than get new value after adding annotation to map. but I see my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding where the problem I was explained how to changed the displayAlert() into

```
func displayAlerts() { // rajish version

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            //            defer { self.dummyFunctionToFoolFirebaseObservers() }
            guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }
            guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }

            //                let date = data!["Date"]
            //                let time = data!["Time"]
            let dataLatitude = data["Latitude"]!
            let dataLongitude = data["Longitude"]!

            let type = data["Description"]!
            let id = Int(data["Id"]!)
            let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
            let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
            let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

            print("Firebase post retrieved !")

            print("Longitude Actual DataKey is \(String(describing: firebaseKey))")

            print("fir long \((snapshot.value!, snapshot.key))")
            var userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: type, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey, title: type,id: id!)
            self.userAlertNotificationArray.append(userAlertAnnotation)  // array of notifications coming from Firebase
            print("user alert array after append from Firebase is : \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")
            self.alertNotificationArray.append(recombinedCoordinate) // array for checkig alerts on route
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(userAlertAnnotation)

        })

    }
```

and the mapView to:

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { // rajish version

```
    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "")


    if annotation is MKUserLocation{
        return nil
    } else {

        print(annotation.coordinate)

        annotationView.image = UIImage(named:(annotationView.annotation?.title)! ?? "")

        //            annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.27, y: 0.27)
        annotationView.transform = transform
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

that solved it.